# LW/MW and FM antenna suggestion for old car radio (25 years old)

Tags: antenna, radio

First of all, i want to listen in my house, you can forget a car. It has been in the warehouse for a long time. Yesterday i tried it. Although I haven't connected an antenna yet, it still works. Because of it has 10-12 cm antenna plug cable probably. As it stands, FM is listened almost perfectly, but i want to improve it. And my main goal is listen to LW/MW. Now i can't listen anything. My first question is:

1. How can i listen LW/MW bands? You can give me a advice about most effective antenna(it can be DIY, i will so happy), because i don't have enough experience about RF, i am young learner :D
2. Actually this is not a question i think. Can i listen LW/MW and FM with same antenna? It would be very good.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep things simple, just by plugging in a 1 to 2 meter wire connected to the center pin of the antenna jack. String it upward, vertically, if possible. That should pick up AM stations in your area, and FM as well.

If you want to pull in more AM stations, make the antenna longer, and hang it higher. If you're picking up too much noise (e.g. from fluorescent lights or motors in your home) you could use a coaxial cable between the antenna and the car radio, moving the antenna onto your roof.

Want to receive distant stations? Google "AM DX" and you'll find hobbyists who are serious about receiving stations from as far away as possible, and they will have plenty of antenna suggestions.